# google vision -" 400 Request must specify image and features" in image to text generation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to write code for event driven cloud function. What this code is supposed to do is whenever an image is uploaded in storage bucket, it will use cloud vision to get text from the image and write the text to a text file and upload it to the same bucket.

```
import os
from google.cloud import storage, vision_v1
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.cloud_event
def image_to_text_storage(cloud_event):
    # Extract relevant information from the Cloud Storage event
    data = cloud_event.data
    bucket_name = data["bucket"]
    object_name = data["name"]

    # Define the local path where you want to save the image and text file
    local_image_file_path = f"/tmp/{os.path.basename(object_name)}"
    local_text_file_path = f"/tmp/{os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(object_name))[0]}.txt"

    # Create a client to interact with Google Cloud Storage
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Access the Google Cloud Storage bucket
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Download the image from Google Cloud Storage to the local /tmp directory
    blob = bucket.blob(object_name)
    with open(local_image_file_path, "wb") as local_image_file:
        blob.download_to_file(local_image_file)

    # Use the Google Cloud vision_v1 API to detect text in the image
    client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    with open(local_image_file_path, "rb") as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()
      
      
    image = vision_v1.Image(content=content)

    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
    detected_text = ""
    if texts:
      detected_text = texts[0].description
    
    print (type(detected_text))
    file_blob = bucket.blob(os.path.basename(local_text_file_path))
    file_blob.upload_from_string(detected_text)

    return "Done"
```

I am running this function using

`gcloud functions deploy image_to_text_storage --gen2 --runtime=python311 --source . --trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" --trigger-event-filters="bucket=<my_bucket>"`

If i print the detected_text, i can see the text in console. However, a empty file is created and i get following error.

```
{
insertId: "***"
labels: {
goog-managed-by: "cloudfunctions"
instanceId: "***"
}
logName: "projects/***/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstdout"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-11-04T12:50:24.559416725Z"
resource: {
labels: {5}
type: "cloud_run_revision"
}
textPayload: "400 Request must specify image and features."
timestamp: "2023-11-04T12:50:24.385989Z"
}
```

I tried using features argument in `response = client.text_detection(image=image)`. However, when text_detection is used, i don't think it allows any features argument. Can you please help here?

Comment: I have also made sure that correct format of image .png is being uploaded to bucket.